# Como posso criar um marcador no OpenStreetMap?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria saber como criar um marcador no OpenStreetMap através de JavaScript, assim como fiz no Google Maps:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i[1],locations[i[2]),
     icon: image,
     map: map
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui...

```
// First create a point geometry (this is the location of the Titanic)
  var point = new Point({
    longitude: -122.084063,
    latitude: 37.422003
  });

  // Create a symbol for drawing the point
  var markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
    color: [226, 119, 40],
    outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
      color: [255, 255, 255],
      width: 2
    }
  });

  // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
  var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: point,
    symbol: markerSymbol
  });
```